# Android Volley getParam() method not call for JsonArrayRequest GET method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, getparameter

I want to do GET request with parameters using volley JsonArrayRequest. I have call getParam() method with parameters but its not calling.

```
JsonArrayRequest jreq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,"http://api.openchargemap.io/v2/poi/",null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    Log.d("TAG", "" + response.toString());
                    if(response.toString().length() > 1) {
                        parseJson(response.toString());
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("TAG",""+error.toString());
        }
    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("output","json");
            map.put("countrycode","US");
            map.put("latitude","32.57933044");
            map.put("longitude","-110.8514633");
            map.put("maxresults","100");
            map.put("distance","10");
            map.put("distanceunit","KM");
            map.put("compact","true");
            map.put("verbose","false");
            return map;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jreq);
```

I am not getting proper response because volley not calling getParam().
I have searched a lot on stack overflow but not get right answer and volley documentation is not good. Thats why I am puting my question here. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code and it's giving me the UnknownHostException. are you sure the url is correct?

Comment: yes. even i am getting response but not proper response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As see here:

[getParams():](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/e7cdf98078bc94a2e430d9edef7e9b01250765ac/src/com/android/volley/Request.java)

> Returns a Map of parameters to be used for a POST or PUT request.  Can
>   throw
>        * {@link AuthFailureError} as authentication may be required to provide these values.
>      ...

So, for  `Request.Method.GET` use `Uri.Builder` instead of overriding `getParams` method for sending query parameters with url

How to use `Uri.Builder` :

```
Uri.Builder urlBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
            builder.scheme("http")
                    .authority("api.openchargemap.io")
                    .appendPath("v2")
                    .appendPath("poi")
                    .appendQueryParameter("output",json)
                    ...// add other paramters in same way
                   ;
```

Get final url from builder:

```
 URL finalURL = new URL(urlBuilder.build().toString());
```

Use `finalURL` url for making GET request.